# How to get the link data with pretty text in it from Google Sheet API

Tags: api, google-sheets

I'm getting data from google sheet in CSV format. But when the sheet has a Hyperlink in its cell, like =Hyperlink("URL", "pretty text"), the google sheet only gives me the pretty text not the link, So my question is how can I get both links & pretty text from google sheet.

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You will have to make use of the `valueRenderOption` parameter when making the `spreadsheets.values.get` API call.

---

**Assuming your cell looks like this:**

[image: sheet with HYPERLINK formula]

You can retrieve the following values using different values for the `valueRenderOption` parameter as this one will determine how values are rendered in the output.

**1. If `valueRenderOption` is `FORMATTED_VALUE`** (which is the *default* value when making the API call):

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEET_ID/values/A1?valueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE
```

Then the response will look like this:

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "pretty text"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**2. If `valueRenderOption` is `UNFORMATTED_VALUE`:**

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEET_ID/values/A1?valueRenderOption=UNFORMATTED_VALUE
```

Then the response will look like this:

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "pretty text"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**3. If `valueRenderOption` is `FORMULA`:**

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEET_ID/values/A1?valueRenderOption=FORMULA
```

Then the response will look like this:

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "=HYPERLINK(\"URL\", \"pretty text\")"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Therefore, depending on the exact result you want to achieve, it would be best to use the `FORMULA` parameter as this will retrieve the formula with its link and value as well. This might require some string processing if you simply want the link and its value.

#### Reference

- [Sheets API spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get);
- [Sheets API ValueRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption).

Comment: I tried this and it did nothing for me. The parameters went through on the string of my GET request. I wonder if I am doing something wrong.